# Getting Null Values when Joining two Dataframes

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am joining two Dataframes based on some common fields - DF1 and DF2. In both the Dataframes I have data extracted from tables which doesn't contain any Null value. When I am joining the Dataframes, the result contains many `Null` values in it. How do I remove these `Null` Values as per there Datatype defined when joining two Dataframes ??

Comment: How to create a [mcve]?

Comment: Could you add some examples of the content in DF1 and DF2. In addition, could you also add the sample code you have tried till now. That will help the SO community to guide you further ...